# VBA excel: how to add text to all files on a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add text string to all files on a folder, as a footer

For example, on the folder on the path and called C:\mobatchscripts\
I have a random number of txt files, with text.
I want to add a line for example "text" on each of the text files on the folder

I have little knowledge of vba programming, but for what I have read I can use append, but I need something that loop on the files on the folder, and modify them.

So far I tried this:

```
Sub footer()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

FolderPath = "C:\mobatchscripts\"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath)


Do While FileName <> ""

Open FileName For Append As #1
Print #1, "test"
Close #1
    FileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

But seems that its not looking into the files, or appending the text.

Comment: No error messages?  Have you tried adding breakpoints and debugging your code?

Comment: Are you appending the string to an excel or text file?

Comment: To a text file, I jut edit my question. I would like to loop into the folder and use append or any other way to add a line with a specific characters

Comment: Open FolderPath & FileName For Append as #1

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you're writing to text files (I see "batchscripts" in the path), you need a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Within the VBE you'll find it in Tools, References)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AppendTextToFiles(strFolderPath As String, _
                            strAppendText As String, _
                            blnAddLine As Boolean)

Dim objFSO      As FileSystemObject
Dim fldOutput   As Folder
Dim filCurrent  As File
Dim txsOutput   As TextStream

Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderPath) Then
    Set fldOutput = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    For Each filCurrent In fldOutput.Files
        Set txsOutput = filCurrent.OpenAsTextStream(ForAppending)
        If blnAddLine Then
            txsOutput.WriteLine strAppendText
        Else
            txsOutput.Write strAppendText
        End If
        txsOutput.Close
    Next

    MsgBox "Wrote text to " & fldOutput.Files.Count & " files", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Path not found", vbExclamation, "Invalid path"
End If

End Sub
```

I'd recommend adding error handling as well and possibly a check for the file extension to ensure that you're writing only to those files that you want to.

To add a line it would be called like this:

```
AppendTextToFiles "C:\mobatchscripts", "Test", True
```

To just add text to the file - no new line:

```
AppendTextToFiles "C:\mobatchscripts", "Test", False
```

Alternatively, forget the params and convert them to constants at the beginning of the proc.  Next time I'd recommend working on the wording of your question as it's not really very clear what you're trying to achieve.